# How might I reformulate a "MM/YYYY" date as "YYYYMM"?

Tags: c#, date, string

I want to convert this string format:

> 11/2013

**TO**

> 201311

So, suppose my string is in this variable:

```
string s = "11/2013";
```

What should be the code for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: "What should be the code" leads us to ask, what have you tried?

Comment: @Marlon - "Can I haz teh spliz code?"

Comment: I would guess it's because you asked a question that you probably could have answered with a Google search in less time than it took to type this up. On the other hand, lots of people got reputation for answering, so I guess it wasn't a total loss :).

Comment: This question is lazy.  All that is needed to answer it is learning the run time library for C#.  If you had done some work and was asking which the best way given some choices or if the way you picked was reasonable, it would have gotten a better reception as an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "11/2011";
s = String.Format("{0}{1}", s.Split('/')[1], s.Split('/')[0]);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 sprime = s.Split(new char [] {'/'});
 s = sprime[1] + sprime[0];
```

This is fastest:

```
 s = s[3] + s[4] + s[5] + s[6] + s[0] + s[1];
```

If you are converting a gazillion billion records it will matter.

Comment: Check your order ;) `s=sprime[1]+sprime[0];`

Comment: Faster, fastest.... If you only need to convert this one record (we don't know) I would say:: string s = "11/2013"; s = "201311"; ;-)

Comment: @HuibertGill - Did you miss the "converting a gazillion billion records" line?

Answer (score 4):

```
string newString = s.Split('/')[1] + s.Split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string [] split = s.Split('/');
string str = split[1] + split[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that this answer assumes `s` will match, and it will return an empty string if it doesn't.

Using `Split` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you try to access `[1]` when there was no `/`.

You could of course add code to handle these cases regardless of whether you use `Regex` or `Split`.

```
string s = "11/2013";

// Match 1+ digits followed by a forward slash followed by 1+ digits
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)/(\d+)");

var m = r.Match(s);
string result = m.Groups[2].Value + m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

All so complicated. Makes my head hurt. Try this instead:

```
static readonly Regex rx = new Regex( @"^(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)$" ) ;
...
string s1 = "12/3456" ;
string s2 = rx.Replace( s1 , @"$2/$1" ) ;
```

Comment: It's two lines of simple, declarative code. Let the regex engine do its thang. If you don't care what the fields contain, replace `\d` with `.`: `new Regex( "^(..)/(....)$" ) ;`. Moreover, you don't need to worry about data that doesn't match: it will be left alone.

Answer (score 1):

Or Splitless for [??]/YYYY; `s.Substring(s.Length - 4, 4) + s.Substring(0, s.Length - 5);`

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "11/2013";
Regex r = new Regex("^(?<month>[0-1]?[0-9])/(?<year>[0-9]{4})$");
var match = r.Match(s);
string month = match.Groups["month"].Value;
string year = match.Groups["year"].Value;
string result = year + month;
```

Comment: sadly this fails to match months appropriately because it allows for months 13-19 and 00. Additionally for years, I see you're planning ahead, allowing everything from 0000 to 9999. Good on ya.

Comment: I'm not planning anything. Question was not how to parse valid dates. Maybe these aren't even dates? How do You know? I just guessed. And think how much money was lost because of not thinking about Y2K when deciding to store year in one byte.

Comment: touche, but look at how you've named them! @Peri the comment was in jest anyways ;)